# Error while cloning opportunities with products

Tags: opportunity, opportunity-lineitem, pricebook

I'm getting this error message:

> An attempt was made to modify the opportunity price book as the opportunity was being cloned.This is not allowed for an opportunity with associated products.

Comment: It is coming from configuration or you have code behind this? Is that multi-currency enabled at your org?

Comment: Its a standard salesforce functionality and how does  multi-currency getting enabled have an impact on this @SantanuBoral

Answer (score 0):

The error is produced as there might be a functionality implemented to update Opportunity with Default Pricebook which is set on current logged in User when an Opportunity is created this applies also, when the Opportunity record is cloned to create a new record.